# Firebase deploy slow and getting a warning

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

When I try to run `Firebase deploy', it stucks at this line of code

```
i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
```

the `firebase init` and `firebase login` are doing fine but `firebase deploy` keeps stuck. My firebase version is `3.18.4` and im currently using ubuntu 17.10.

EDIT:
and after waiting for about an hour it diplays this line of code

```
FIREBASE WARNING: auth() was canceled: Auth token is expired.
```

Am I doing something wrong?. I am new to Firebase and I need some tips/ advice on why this happening

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tip, that might help you. Give it a try and tell me if it resolves your issue.

Always use these commands instead of just **firebase deploy**

**firebase deploy --only hosting**

**firebase deploy --only functions** <<- use this in ur case. Also make sure your in the directory **/functions** of your project where you ran your **firebase init**

Comment: I got an error on firebase deploy --only hosting ERROR: `Cannot understand what targets to deploy` but firebase deploy --only functions works for me. Anyway thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes Firebase services may be down, which would prevent you from deploying your code. If you can't deploy, check this site and see if at least all services are up and running: https://status.firebase.google.com/

Comment: Okay I'll check it out. Thanks!