# Large Firebase hosting deploy error with auth token expired

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to deploy Firebase hosting via `firebase deploy`. However, my hosting directory is pretty large (~15gb) so it takes a while. After ~1hr, I get a warning `FIREBASE WARNING: auth() was canceled: Auth token is expired.`, then proceeds to fail with `Error: An unexpected error has occurred.`.

I've tried logging in via `firebase login:ci` and using `firebase deploy --token` and same error too.

How can I fix this error and deploy a large hosting directory?
Version: `firebase-tools@3.18.4`

Note: I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853427/firebase-deploy-slow-and-getting-a-warning) post but it doesn't seem to solve my answer either.

Comment: Right now it's probably very difficult to deploy a 15GB directory to Firebase Hosting. If you have large files that don't change frequently, Cloud Storage is probably a better fit for them. We're working on improvements to deployment infrastructure that should help here, but don't have any definitive timeline to announce.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh I'm having the same problem with 4.3MB... currently doing some research, before contacting support [EDIT] ... and as soon I made the comment try to deploy again and took 1 sec to see the success message :/